# How to access array element in symfony controller

Tags: php, doctrine

How to access the element from the array set within controller. I'm not sure how to access it

```
  ArrayCollection {#2052 ▼
    -elements: array:2 [▼
         0 => Education {#2085 ▼
           -id: 11
            -title: "aaaaaaaaaaaaa"
           -degreeId: Degree {#2103 ▶}
           -yearFrom: DateTime {#1411 ▶} 
    }
    1 => Education {#2100 ▼
         -id: 12
       -title: "bbbbbbbbbbbb"
          -degreeId: Degree {#2099 ▶}
      -yearFrom: DateTime {#2102 ▶}
      -yearTo: DateTime {#2101 ▶} 
  }
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access all

```
foreach ($yourArrayCollectionName as $element) {
  // here you have your elements
}
```

otherwise, if you need a specific element

```
$yourArrayCollectionName->get($indexOfElement);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it and let you know